# Using output from a PowerShell command in a windows batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command

I have a path in variable (script parameter) `%2`.
I need to do  the following:

1. Extract the leaf (last folder from the path) to a variable.
2. Run the following command: `robocopy %2 \\somepath\%leaf`

I was told this could be done in PowerShell (cause I've tried going with batch file alone and failed miserably) Here's a pseudocode representation of what I'd like to achieve:

```
set leaf = powershell -command (split-path %2 -leaf)
robocopy %2 \\somepath\%leaf
```

Any idea how to write this correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give me an example with some mock folder names?  I'm having a hard time following you with your usage of %2.  Batch scripting is not a strength of mine, while PowerShell is.

Comment: I'm sorry but that would be of no use to me. Just like you, I can code in PowerShell, not Batch. I need to write the the batch command so that it'll work in my batch script, with the %2 and all.

Comment: any reason why you can't run robocopy from within powershell. In theory you could use batch FOR statement to get the output from powershell but why?? e.g. $leaf = (split-path %2 -leaf); robocopy %2 \somepath\$leaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to set a batch variable to the output of a command, use `for /f`.  Here's an example:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "psCommand=powershell -command "(split-path '%~2' -leaf)""
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%psCommand%') do set "leaf=%%I"

echo %leaf%
```

But this is a terribly inefficient way to retrieve the last folder of a path.  Instead of invoking PowerShell, what you *should* do is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in ("%~2") do set "leaf=%%~nxI"

echo %leaf%
```

The `%%~dpnxI` notation gets

- d = drive
- p = path
- n = name
- x = extension

It's traditionally intended for files, rather than directories; but it works just as well for directories anyway.  See the last couple of pages of `for /?` in a console window for complete details.

Comment: Thanks, that finally worked (the second option). I have no idea how or why it works, and I've been battling with this for hours. Also, in your first example, why is robocopy part of the powershell command?

Comment: @Shaggydog Your question was originally formatted with `robocopy` on the same line as `split-path`.  I didn't pay close enough attention to whether that was valid PowerShell-ese or not.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR %%a IN ("%~2") DO FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO %%~nxb
```

Batch one-liner. Take the parameter (second parameter here), remove any quotes and re-apply them. Select the drive and path, add '.' then select the name and extension of the result making leaf required.

Obviously, if you require this in a variable,

```
FOR %%a IN ("%~2") DO FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpa.") DO set "leaf=%%~nxb"
```